# What is the name of this puzzle?

Tags: puzzle

Anyone knows what is the name of this puzzle: [image: A puzzle from a hotel]

Answer (score 3):

[Gordian's Knot](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EGI4OO) by ThinkFun. $~~~~$

Comment: And reasonably priced! [http://www.amazon.com/Think-Fun-6820-ThinkFun-Gordians/dp/B000EGI4OO]  I tried an image search on the posted photo, with hilarious consequences. A search on the name led to an interesting page on this puzzle here:  http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~efif/applications/puzzles/knot/.  [Spoiler page here: http://www.geocities.ws/abcmcfarren/math/gordian.htm ]